# How to run rails server on termux, inside Samsung Dex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, termux, samsung-dex

Samsung Dex in only an aclaration, as it handles termux as any Android environment.

I want to run a local rails server in my android environment by using termux. I want help to know what dependencies and installations I have to configure to be successful.

Answer (score 0):

**Rails 6.0.3.2 on Termux**

```
pkg upgrade
pkg install ruby vim git nodejs
```

nokogiri will build natively and would need the ff packages and will need pkg-config to find them:

- libxml-2
- libxslt
- libexslt

so install pkg-config

```
pkg install pkg-config
```

libxml-2 (2.9.10-3) is installed when you run:

```
pkg install build-essentials
```

<s>pkg install libxslt</s>

pkg install libexslt will not work, I guess it's already bundled with libxslt

tried running:

```
gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
```

nokogiri was successfully installed

finally install rails without docs, we dont want them taking up space:

```
gem install rails --no-doc
```

libsqlite for sqlite3 gem

```
pkg install libsqlite
```

install yarn first before running rails new:

```
pkg install yarn
```

ffi and rb-inotify are already included via bundle when you run:
rails new

```
gem install tzinfo-data
```

tzinfo-data issue when running rails server:
rubygems/rubygems#3212

try removing the Gemfile.lock and running the bundle install again.
or
Running bundle update tzinfo

What worked for me is changing tzinfo-data gem in Gemfile from:

> gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

to

> gem 'tzinfo-data'

then deleting Gemfile.lock and running bundle install again

now run the server via `rails server` and browse `localhost:3000` on any browser on your device.

All is well until we create our first controller and change the routes root path:

```
rails generate controller Dashboard index
```

and on config/routes.rb file:

```
root to: 'dashboard#index'
```

then browsing again to our browser on `localhost:3000` gives us this ActionVew::TemplateError:

```
Webpacker can't find application in <my app path>/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{
}
```

tried running compilation on test environment:

```
RAILS_ENV=test NODE_ENV=test bundle exec rails webpacker:compile
```

this returns `Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen`

I haven't found a solution to this issue at the time of this writing.

Answer (score -1):

Steps:

1. Install termux and run it. Run following commands:
2. apt update
3. apt upgrade
4. apt install ruby cmake sqlite libxslt node.js yarn
5. xcode-select install `(this command might be avoidable)`
6. gem install rails
7. pkg install wget
8. wget https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/files/2912002/fix-ruby-bigdecimal.sh.txt
9. bash fix-ruby-bigdecimal.sh.txt `This later 3 commands are for fixing bigdecimal problem`
10. rails webpacker:install
11. Inside each rails project you work on, modify gemfile as follows:
    replace

`# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]`

for

```
gem 'tzinfo-data', '~> 1.2019', '>= 1.2019.2'
```

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57538377/5750078)

This should at least solve most of my encountered problems